# How to combine multiple SPF domains, one with an mx mechanism?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, mx-record, txt-record

I combined 3 SPF records using the standard protocol, but got a null error after combining them.

Individual records:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.sendinblue.com mx ~all

v=spf1 include:dc-aa8e722993._spfm.example.org ~all

v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

After combining:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.sendinblue.com mx include:dc-aa8e722993._spfm.example.org include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

The problem is now when I check it, I get a null for the **include:dc-aa8e722993._spfm.example.org** portion.

I am not techy enough to figure this out on my own, any suggestions on how to properly combine these/what might be wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The combined record is syntactically correct. Did you check the problematic record individually? Does the record include other spf records? You might run into the limit of maximal 10 nested includes.